# Sumproduct with multiple criteria and week range - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, sumproduct

I m using `SUMPRODUCT()` function to get the score of each student under multiple criteria.
In the below scenarion the criterias are:

1. Name: A
2. Week: 42 (falls in range 41 - 45)
3. Type: Exam

Using

```
=SUMPRODUCT((R2:R6=R8)*AND((S2:S6>=R9)*(T2:T6<=R9))*(U2:U6=R10);V2:V6)
```

i don't manage to get and success. Going through the formula i have understand that i do not manage to get the correct period.

Any ideas how to look on the correct time range?

[image]

Comment: Try: `=SUMPRODUCT((R8=$R$2:$R$6)*(R10=$U$2:$U$6)*(R9>=$S$2:$S$6)*(R9<=$T$2:$T$6)*$V$2:$V$6)`

Comment: Btw `SUMIFS` can be used here as well.

Comment: `TRUE * TRUE` makes sense, `AND(TRUE, TRUE)` too, but `AND(TRUE * TRUE, <nothing>)` not :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `SUMPRODUCT()` function in the following manner as shown in the screenshot, also `MS365` users can use `SUM()` function here:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>R11</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT((R8=R2:R6)*(R10=U2:U6)*(R9>=S2:S6)*(R9<=T2:T6)*V2:V6)
```

---

Edit: Also ensure to change the separators to the one that supports your regional settings, i.e. in place of commas it would be semi-colon `;`. This is not needed as the formula multiplies the arrays and sum as well.

[image]

---

You don't need the `AND()` function in the formula as well, as `*` operator acts as the `AND()` function, and just for information the `+` would act as `OR()`.